# Target [App\Http\Requests\Request] is not instantiable

Tags: laravel

I am unable to understand why this error appears. I have created a function for user to give its credentials and log in.

Route of the function is

```
Route::any('login','UserController@authenticate');

public function authenticate(Request $request) {
   if($request->isMethod('post')) {
   $email = $request->input('email');
   $password = $request->input('password');
   if(Auth::attempt(array('email' => $email, 'password' => $password), true)) {
   return redirect()->intended('publicPages.home_startup')->withErrors('Congratulations! You are logged in');
   } else {
return redirect()->intended('publicPages.login')->withErrors('Sorry! Login    Failed');
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 36):

You will probably need this line of code in the top.

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
```

If you have it, you can upload the project to a repository to help better?

Comment: I am using `use App\Http\Requests\Request` upon this it gives and error and when i changed it to `use Illuminate\Http\Request;`it shows blank page. @ItaloMoralesF

Comment: @QasimAli the App\Http\Requests\Request class is Abstract, and therefore can't be instantiated by design. Using Illuminate\Http\Request is the correct method.

Answer (score 0):

Try the above answer or this, both are the same

```
public function authenticate(Illuminate\Http\Request $request) {
       if($request->isMethod('post')) {
       $email = $request->input('email');
       $password = $request->input('password');
       if(Auth::attempt(array('email' => $email, 'password' => $password), true)) {
       return redirect()->intended('publicPages.home_startup')->withErrors('Congratulations! You are logged in');
       } else {
    return redirect()->intended('publicPages.login')->withErrors('Sorry! Login    Failed');
                    }
                }
            }
```